# OnClick for Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I'm new to ASP.NET and C# and also new to this forum but here is my problem.
I'm trying to create a image gallery with ASP.NET Webforms(requirement) and C#. I'm using a Listview to show the thumbnails and when you click on the small picture the big version should show above in a img tag for example. But I cant find any "OnClick" code for a hyperlink. Do I have to do that with JavaScript? 
Thanks for all help.

here is some of the code:

```
<ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:HyperLink ID="ImageHyperLink" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Name","~/files/thumbs/{0}") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Name","~/files/{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>               
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: can you please show your code what you have tried ?

Comment: can I write code behind when I click on one of the pictures?

Answer (score 5):

Try taking a look at `LinkButton`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LinkButton1" OnClick="OnClickAction"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This will allow you to do a server-side method in much the same way an `<asp:Button>` will do. However will look just like a hyperlink.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that instead. Like I said I'm very new to all of this. Must say I'm very impressed by the quick response. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl="http://stackoverflow.com/">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

You will not get on click event for `HyperLink`, But for navigating on to the another page.

You will get one property which is `NavigateUrl`

By using this property you can redirect to any page by giving url.

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://stackoverflow.com/">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. Like I said I'm very new to all of this. Thank you!